# what application designs are there to prevent other users from working on the same task

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, database-design, user-interface

Say you have a windows desktop application that has a grid with orders placed by our customers that need to be processed and entered by the staff into another external system.

So the customers order from us and we place these orders with our suppliers. Each staff has this desktop application installed on their PC.

So what UI design or application designs are there to prevent users working and processing the same order? Right now user 1 starts at the top of the grid and user 2 starts at the bottom of the grid but the problem is that they overlap when they come to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are various approaches. E.g.

1. Show them disjunct lists. If they don't see the same tasks, they won't process the same. Well you have to define a criteria after which the application omits some tasks, but you'll find one.
2. Let the user mark the task and the application respond, that the user can process this task. A usual scenario might be

   - User1 selects taskA and marks it with process
   - Application stores that mark in the DB
   - User2 selects taskA and marks it also
   - Application revokes the mark on taskA because it's already marked
   - User2 has to selected another task

There might be some other possibilities, but these are the first, which came into my mind.